How do I check with TRUE/FALSE return if there are NAs in a R SpatRaster?
I'm trying to check for NAs (missing values) in my SpatRaster (is a bioclimatic raster from CHELSA from ex [DOWNLOAD the raster 117MB] https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/chelsav2/GLOBAL/climatologies/1981-2010/bio/CHELSA_bio10_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif) but I can't find the function that returns TRUE if there are NAs or FALSE if there is no NA in my raster.
I try with anyNA function but it does not return a TRUE or FALSE response
r <- rast("~/Downloads/CHELSA_bio10_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif")
r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 20880, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180.0001, 179.9999, -90.00014, 83.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : CHELSA_bio10_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif 
name        : CHELSA_bio10_1981-2010_V.2.1 

anyNA(r)
class       : SpatRaster                  
dimensions  : 20880, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180.0001, 179.9999, -90.00014, 83.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : spat_40430ebe563_1028.tif 
varname     : CHELSA_bio10_1981-2010_V.2.1 
name        : CHELSA_bio10_1981-2010_V.2.1 
min value   :                        FALSE 
max value   :                        FALSE 

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for help,

You already have the information within min and max values of results. Use minmax() function to retrieve it:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.8.3

r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, nlyrs=1)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r) * nlyr(r))
anyNA(r) |>
  minmax() |>
  any() |>
  suppressWarnings()
#> [1] FALSE

set.seed(3)
v <- values(r)
v[sample(length(v), 10)] <- NA
values(r) <- v
anyNA(r) |>
  minmax() |>
  any() |>
  suppressWarnings()
#> [1] TRUE

And with your raster:
r <- terra::rast("~/Downloads/CHELSA_bio10_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif")
anyNA(r) |>
  minmax() |>
  any() |>
  suppressWarnings()
#> [1] FALSE

Created on 2024-12-17 with reprex v2.1.1.9000

You can use terra::global(x, fun="anyNA") for that.
library(terra)
#terra 1.8.5

r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10, nlyrs=10, vals=1:1000)
r[[2:5]][1] <- NA

global(r, "anyNA")
#       anyNA
#lyr.1  FALSE
#lyr.2   TRUE
#lyr.3   TRUE
#lyr.4   TRUE
#lyr.5   TRUE
#lyr.6  FALSE
#lyr.7  FALSE
#lyr.8  FALSE
#lyr.9  FALSE
#lyr.10 FALSE

This is more efficient that first computing anyNA(r).
